# Translation of "perros de charro"

Tags: traducción

I do not see any glue to get the meaning of this word connection. Nor when looking at google image search result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Perros **de charro**" are *funny looking dogs*.

["Charro"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charro) is a Mexican word to refer a horseman but it can have additional meanings like "flashy" and "gaudy" (see [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=charro)), and there are even some [regional variations](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Charro.php) of the meaning the word depending on the country.

- In Argentina seems to be a joint (marihuana cigarette)
- In Colombia seems to be a funny situation, or something boring and ugly.
- In Dominican Republic is something ugly or low quality
- In Guatemala and Puerto Rico seems to be something ridiculous.

So the expression "perros de charro" may have a different meaning for different Spanish speakers. For some, it would be the dogs of a Mexican horseman / cowboy. For others, it would be dogs that look funny, ugly or ridiculous (like "perros de risa", "perros graciosos" or "perros raros").

Some of the results in google images when searching for "perros de charro", are dogs dressed like tiny *mariachis* or *charros*, with *sombrero* and everything, which I guess may combine most of the above definitions (something ridiculously funny, a dog dressed like a *charro*), but if I had to stick to only one meaning I would choose "funny because it is ridiculous". That is why "perros the charro" translates as **funny looking dogs**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Such cute dog!! :)

Answer (score 3):

In South America, this kind of dogs are called chihuahua/chihuahueño.

If you search them by using that name, you would find them.

Certainly "charro" will have diferent meanings but the nearliest meaning of " perros de charro" will be "chihuahueño or chihuahua "

I hope I helped.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: Wow, never knew that it meant chihuahua/chihuahueño. I love them, They are so cute!!!

Answer (score 1):

May I add, the word "charro" is originally from the Salamanca province in Spain.

When somebody from there "va de charro" (goes [dressing] in charro way) he/she is wearing the traditional clothes from the region. In the case of the man is a mix of the "Zorro" suit with colorful waist and a bit strange hat. Such dress is probably the arcane origin of the Mexican expression.

(I was born there).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perros de charros means gaudy dogs. Gaudy is Mexican cowboy/cowgirl. A gaudy dog is actually a "Chiuhua".

[image]